# How to encode a string to base64 encoding algorithm using PowerBuilder

Tags: java, powerbuilder

Requirement:

- Given a String
- we need to generate Base64 encoded string using the above given string.

How can we implement it using powerBuilder.

For reference, The Java implementation of the above case is as follows:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    public String getClientEncoded() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String givenString= "Input_String";
        String bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(valueToHash.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("encoded value is " + bytesEncoded);
        return bytesEncoded ;
    }
```

============================================================

As per Matt's reply, Used this below code from the 1st link:

```
String ls_valueToBeEncoded
blob lblob

ls_valueToBeEncoded = "realhowto"
lblob = Blob(ls_valueToBeEncoded)
ULong lul_len, lul_buflen
Boolean lb_rtn

lul_len = Len(ablob_data)

lul_buflen = lul_len * 2

ls_encoded = Space(lul_buflen)

lb_rtn = CryptBinaryToString(ablob_data, &
lul_len, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, &
ref ls_encoded, lul_buflen) // Used ref ls_encoded to get the string. Otherwise, junk characters gets stored in ls_encoded.`
=======================================

Used the below code in Global External Function:
`FUNCTION boolean CryptBinaryToString ( &
Blob pbBinary, &
ulong cbBinary, &
ulong dwFlags, &
Ref string pszString, &
Ref ulong pcchString ) &
LIBRARY "crypt32.dll" ALIAS FOR "CryptBinaryToStringA;Ansi"`
```

=========================================

According to the 1st link suggested by Matt, The string `"realhowto"` should be converted to `"cmVhbGhvd3Rv."`
But when I tried the above code, I got `"cgBlAGEAbABoAG8AdwB0AG8A"`

Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: Not done this but you might try the unicode api call. CryptBinaryToStringW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0258.html)

Make sure you look at the comments as well.

Another option [is here.](https://www.example-code.com/powerbuilder/crypt_base64.asp)

Real's How To is a very good reference for many PowerBuilder tips.

Answer (score 0):

Checked with the 1st [link](http://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0258.html) given by Matt.
The solution worked.
Only thing I was missing earlier was while converting the original string to blob, we need to convert via the following:

```
String ls_original_string
Blob lblob_test
lblob_test = Blob(ls_original_string, EncodingAnsi!)
```

The blob lblob_test can be passed as an argument to the function `CryptBinaryToString(...)`

Answer (score 0):

My encryption examples also have the API functions used by Real's example.

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_bcrypt.html